# Why is Chome devtools automatically blocking a request?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a PWA (Progressive Web App) but the Chrome devtools console is warning that it is blocking my css and icon file.

```
Request was blocked by DevTools: "https://example.com/styles/style.css".
```

I cannot find any information about this happening automatically and, to my knowledge, should only happen if the user has manually requested to block a script. Chrome does not offer any other information about the warnings other than being blocked.

Comment: Same here. I closed and opened the devtools, and it was gone. Does nobody have an idea what this message is about?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @user1383029 ... Closing the dev tools and re-opening them fixes the problem. Couldn't tell you why or how this started happening. I even disabled request blocking in chrome and it was still blocking requests.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error means the domain or URL has been blocked in the devtools. Most of the time, it's just because the developer blocked the request without paying attention.

To unblock it, just follow these steps:

- Open your devtools
- Go to the network tab
- Right-click on the request that blocked
- Then click `Unblock <request-url>`

[image: Chrome Inspector - Unblock Request URL]

Comment: Also check in the "Request blocking" tab for any blockings with wildcards (e.g. `localhost:3000/icons/*`). Anyway, it still blocks request in my case when using the Lightouse performance analyzer.

Comment: My other comment seems to have vanished and I don't know why. Anyway, this doesn't answer the question, which is _why_ is Chrome DevTools blocking the request. It just restates information that's already included in the question. It also implies that it's probably due to developer error, which is a huge (and inaccurate) assumption.

Comment: Unblock isn't an option in the menu

Answer (score 0):

While you on devTools, just press ESC and you will see this tabs:

**Console** / **Issues** / **Network request blocking** / **What's New** and **Search**
go to **Network request blocking tab** and there you can uncheck all that you have blocked sometime. In my case was localhost.

[image: Console after ESC]

After that press once again ESC.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I tried to add a favicon to my website. But after changing the favicon location the issue disappeared.

I chaged `.favicon.ico` to `./assets/images/favicon.ico`