# Browser is blocking images and API calls

Tags: xmlhttprequest

When my page loads it requests `/settings` to load settings.
This worked yesterday but today Firefox has started blocking this saying

> `Blocked by DevTools`

The `favicon` is also being blocked.

Firefox doesn't give any information about why it is doing this.

The requsts is on the same origin, so it can't be CORS.

Chrome and Edge also block them, but give even less information.

How can I get it to work again.

[image]

`/settings` is working in my Angular app but not React, so I think it's something to do with React.

Comment: Maybe the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598435/why-is-chome-devtools-automatically-blocking-a-request

Comment: No. Checked that already. Besides, Chrome and Edge also have the same problem.