# In Firefox and Safari, JS Fetch API fails to send POST requests from React app deployed to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, express, http, fetch-api, netlify

I deployed a multi-page React frontend (built with React Router) to Netlify and a Node + Express backend to Cyclic. When users submit an [account creation form](https://main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app/register) from within my React app, the form data are supposed to be sent to my Express server via a POST request.

Fortunately, in Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Brave, the POST request is successfully sent, and my server provides an appropriate response (i.e., all the contents of the form, which constitute the request body as well). But in Firefox and Safari the POST request is blocked. In Firefox I get an error message stating that the request is blocked by DevTools, along with the message "NS_BINDING_ABORTED" (rather than the usual "cached") in the Network Monitor under the heading "Transferred."

[POST blocked by DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzfsn.png)

[NS_BINDING_ABORTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU3Xd.png)

Safari's developer tools, on the other hand, fail to provide any error messages as far as I can tell.

Here is my code:

```
const postReq = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(formData),
};

fetch('https://weak-puce-toad-garb.cyclic.app/', postReq).catch((error) =>
   console.log(error)
);
```

I had read online that adding Expires headers to my Express server's responses to POST requests might resolve the NS_BINDING_ABORTED issue in Firefox. But that made no difference whatsoever to which browsers blocked the requests and which didn't.

To enable POST requests in Safari, some suggested avoiding the use of async/await syntax, as you can see I have done. That made no difference either. Someone else suggested adding a terminating forward slash to the URL passed to fetch(). I had already done that, so instead I added a terminating forward slash to the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, that being the URL of my Netlify production deploy: https://main--fascinating-melba-bd8f4d.netlify.app

But tacking a slash onto the end of that URL had no effect.

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions enabled in Firefox that might be interfering (eg an ad-blocker)?

Comment: FYI `Origin` values are always just scheme and host, no path so you won't want a `/` suffix

Comment: No ad blocker, but I do have the following extensions enabled: React Developer Tools, Sidebery, and Tab Session Manager. Might one of those be the culprit?

Comment: Try disabling them and find out ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Also check Firefox's settings. They could be [blocking what is deemed as a tracking URL](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Disabling all of those Firefox extensions simultaneously did nothing though. :(

Still looking into this Enhanced Tracking Protection business.

Comment: I tried simply turning off Enhanced Tracking Protection for my Netlify production site, but that didn't help. Then I went a step further and changed the protection settings from Standard to Custom, proceeding to unblock (in non-private windows) cookies, tracking content, cryptominers, and fingerprinters. No luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Chome devtools automatically blocking a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598435/why-is-chome-devtools-automatically-blocking-a-request)

Comment: The popup says 'blocked by devtools'. Firefox has a 'Request Blocking' feature. Did you turn it on?

Comment: I'm guessing your issue could be exactly this one here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496459/1427878 ? I see your aborted POST request in FF dev tools, directly followed by a GET request for `/register?` - a pretty clear sign, that your form submitted "the normal way". (None of your form fields have a `name`, so that explains the "empty" query string.)

Comment: @Evert That doesn't directly answer my question, since only Firefox's DevTools block the request, not Chrome's. To my knowledge I have not turned on Request Blocking in Firefox. I don't know where I would go to toggle that feature. And when I right-click the row highlighted in blue in the Network tab (second image), the dropdown includes no option to unblock the URL, only to block it—which I never selected.

Comment: @sophias-fault have you looked into what I mentioned yet?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you may have pointed me in the right direction. Though my submit button is not missing the attribute "type" with a value of "submit", it may well be that I should have used a button element rather than an input element as my submit button. As things stand, I'm using an input element with a type of submit, but customizing its submission functionality by passing a callback as the value of its onClick attribute. In other words, I'm not taking advantage of the input element's built-in submission capabilities. That may cause problems.